# Display wordpress blogroll with html interpretation in description

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm willing to use the blogroll capability of wordpress to display a list of partners on my site. I want to know how can I use the field `Description` in the link page of wordpress to accept html tags like `<a>`, `<p>` etc?

I can display the `description`, but it don't interpretate the tags. For example, if I put in the description

```
This is the description of our partner. His <a href="www.bla.com">Website</a> is cool
```

then I'll get the same text as plain text on the site, without link!

How can I make it?

Comment: are you talking about "Links" manager? when you add new link the description field accepts tags, i just checked the database and it has the tags in

Comment: If you dig deep into the bookmark functions you will find that the `link_description` is run through `esc_attr()` this is because the original intention of the description field was to use it as the title attribute of the link.

Comment: Hi @Jrod. I tried to remove the `esc_attr` function call from the line  `desc = esc_attr(sanitize_bookmark_field('link_description', $bookmark->link_description, $bookmark->link_id, 'display'));` but it does not have any effect.

Comment: I don't recommend modifying core files.  Depending on how you are retrieving the info the line you removed may not be used.  What might work is running the description through `wp_specialchars_decode`

Comment: The problem is, i'm calling the list from page.php with this line `wp_list_bookmarks( $args );`... there is no way to parse the description, right?

Comment: You cannot, no.  Also, As far as I know, WordPress removed the blogroll feature as of last year.  Your best bet is to create a custom menu with the links saved in Appearance > Menus and display that instead.

Comment: This is the first time I see someone cross-posting a Question with [wordpress.se] and not simply copy-pasting the Q. Kudos for that! I'll cross-post my Answer here too ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant core ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21307) regarding the future removal of Links from the core and conversion into a plugin.

---

To enable HTML tags in the `Description` field (and in the `Notes` field), use the following code:

```
// Disable the removal of HTML tags
remove_filter( 'pre_link_description', 'wp_filter_kses' );
remove_filter( 'pre_link_notes', 'wp_filter_kses' );

// Enable HTML tags the same way as in posts content
add_filter( 'pre_link_description', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
add_filter( 'pre_link_notes', 'wp_filter_post_kses' );
```

Comment: Tahnks for your reply. I put this code on my page.php, just before `wp_list_bookmarks( $args );` and it didn't have any effect  :-(

Comment: You've got to add it to your theme's `functions.php`, or in a [functionality plugin](http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/).